# how to load video from local dsk to android emulator?

Tags: android

I am new to android development. looking to develop one application. where I need to extract audio files from video and also need to extract video as frames by giving video file as input in android application?

How to achieve this?

Comment: your post subject says something else, and inside the question you are asking is something else. Please be clear about what you want. If you just want to push a video file onto the emulator, then you can do so either using `DDMS` or through `adb push` command.

Comment: actually, I have to load video file, then I need to extract frames and audio from that video.

Comment: my intention is to extract frames and audio from video file.